# How to apply Date format to the Imported Range

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, import, number-formatting

I have a question, how to apply date format to the results comming from query(Importrange) formula.

My formula "=filter({A:A,row(A:A)},isnumber(A:A))" in B1 can't see these dates. Spreadsheet only can see this as a text, not number.

[image]

[Spreadsheet with example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7zGxBIF2JqZUfvqKtP_ZurmUkv_mV41MzlqKVh4WJg/edit?usp=sharing)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER({A:A, ROW(A:A)}, ISNUMBER(A:A*1))
```

[image]